# Update a List by batch then join back

Tags: java, java-8

My purpose: update the Availability of the employee list

```
List<Employee> employees = ...;

//separated to a List of "20 item list"
List<List<Employee>> separatedEmployees = ListUtils.partition(employees, 20); 

//update availability by each "20 item List"
separatedEmployees.parallelStream()
    .forEach(item -> updateAvailability(user, null, item)); 

//get back whole list
List<Employee> employeesAfterUpdate= separatedEmployees
    .stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Work totally fine but I wonder there are any different implementation/approach that I don't need to create a buffer `List<List<Employee>> separatedEmployees` because it's hard for me to explain to someone else (little technical knowledge) about a `List` of a `List`

Comment: Why do you need to split the list before streaming it? Can't you call `parallelStream` on your original list?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson because I want to process a list of 20 items at a time. Not 1 item at a time. So I split it by 20 then stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `StreamEx` library for this:

```
List<Employee> updatedEmployees = StreamEx.ofSubLists(employees, 20)
            .parallel()
            .map(items -> updateAvailability(user, null, items))
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can replace `map` with `peek` if `updateAvailability` returns void, although `peek` is for debug only. I would suggest to change `updateAvailability` so it returns a new list or an updated one

Comment: Where do we get StreamEx from?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.amaembo/streamex

Answer (score 2):

After reading the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55629545/9218757), turn out I can just use `peek` (instead of `forEach`) item then collect back to a `list` in just one `stream`

```
List<Employee> employees = ...;
List<Employee> employeesAfterUpdate = ListUtils.partition(employees, 20)
    .parallelStream()
    .peek(item -> updateAvailability(user, null, item))
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```